# Insert into Table from select Query Temporal

Tags: sql, teradata, temporal

```
Insert into TableA as
( nonsequenced validtime
 select id,type from TableB );
```

Here Table A is non temporal. which has only id and type columns

Insert failed 3707: syntax error

Basically i want to insert result of temporal select query to non temporal volatile table.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the correct syntax:

```
nonsequenced validtime
Insert into TableA
select id,type from TableB;
```